# Trouble with requests' get in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, download, python-requests

I am trying to automatically download files from a website using a list of URLs that I already have. The relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
for url in urls:
    if len(url) != 0:
        print url
```

Running this prints a list of urls as strings - as expected. However, when I add one new line as below:

```
for url in urls:
    if len(url) != 0:
        print url
        r = requests.get(url)
```

an error appears saying "Invalid URL u'Document Detail': No schema supplied." Before this breaks, it is supposed to print a url. Previously, this printed the url as expected. However, now it prints "Document Detail" instead of a URL. I'm not quite sure why this happens and how to resolve it.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

```
urls = []
with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    count = 0
    for row in reader:
        urls.append(row[34])
```

Comment: What is the value of `urls` variable?

Comment: @alecxe urls is a list of lists

Comment: can you show how you assign the `urls` variable?

Comment: I will post it into the main post under EDIT. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have an idea of where Document Details comes from? Rather, could we see a sample of the first few lines of your csv?

Comment: @sihrc Ah I think you found the problem! Document Details is the header in the csv file. Do you know how I can skip it when adding things to urls? readline()? Thanks so much!

Comment: readline() can work. csv also has some classes that could do it as well. readline() approach just index it off (reader[1:]) and split on commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to my comment, "Document Details" is the header of your csv. Skip it. Here's one way to do it.

```
urls = []
with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as f:
    read = f.readlines()
    urls = [row.split(",")[34] for row in read[1:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the layout of your csv file has changed and the url is no longer in column **33** i.e. (34 - 1 since `rows` is zero based).

Comment: I feel that the csv file should not be the problem, I have run the program multiple times without the file changing and checked it too. The error only appears once I add the last line "r = requests.get(url)". If I comment that out it prints all of the URLs again.

Answer (score 0):

The you should convert url to string explicitly:

```
for url in urls:
    if len(url) != 0:
        print str(url)
        r = requests.get(str(url))
```

And maybe you can give us some piece of your .csv file please.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I think I have found the error, it was the header in the csv file that was causing problems! I'm quite new to this, so how should I denote this as solved?